# SourceBuffer.remove(start, end) removes whole buffered TimeRange (How to handle realtime stream with MSE?)

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, html5-video, media-source

I have a [`SourceBuffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SourceBuffer/) with a single entry in [`.buffered`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SourceBuffer/buffered). I have a realtime stream of raw h.264 data arriving which I encode into mp4 and push into the `SourceBuffer` with [`.appendBuffer(data)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SourceBuffer/appendBuffer). Since this is a realtime stream of data I need to keep clearing the buffer however this is where I encounter my problem. (Ie. I encounter a [`QuotaExceededError`](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/10/quotaexceedederror))

For examples sake my single entry in `SourceBuffer.buffered` has a timerange of 0-10 seconds. My attempt to tidy the buffer is to call [`SourceBuffer.remove(0, 8)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SourceBuffer/remove). My expectation is that my buffer would be cleared and I'd be left with a timerange of 8-10. However the entire timerange (my only range) is removed and from this point all further appendBuffer calls seem to do nothing.

Three questions relevant to this issue:

1. How do I a) stop .remove from having this behaviour or b) force new time-ranges in my buffer so that only "old" ranges are removed.
2. Why do the later `appendBuffer` calls do nothing? I would expect them to re-populate the `SourceBuffer`.
3. Is there a better ["MSE"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Media_Source_Extensions_API) way to handle a realtime stream where I never care about going back in time? Ie. All rendered data can be thrown away.

In case there's some weird Browser/Platform issue going on I'm using Chrome on Ubuntu.

Also, I am basing my code off of https://github.com/xevokk/h264-converter.

Comment: "Since this is a realtime stream of data I need to keep clearing the buffer"  It's been some years since I've messed with this, but I don't remember ever having to clear past buffer with realtime streams.  I just kept appending more, and let the browser evict old data.  I could be wrong about this though.  Did you have an issue where memory was continuously being consumed?

Comment: Yes, in chrome i get a `QuotaExceededError` at around 150mb. Details here: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/10/quotaexceedederror

Comment: In my experience, Chrome doesn't always produce this error at 150Mb of appended data, if anyone was wondering. I have just tested with having appended over a gigabyte of data and no `QuotaExceededError` was thrown. However, I can see with the video object that is connected to the media source, that even though the entire timeline is seekable -- around an hour of media -- only last 8 minutes actually are buffered and thus can be played, suggesting to me that Chrome has removed everything else as it deemed necessary.

Answer (score 3):

It's all in the MSE spec.

http://w3c.github.io/media-source/#sourcebuffer-coded-frame-removal

Step 3.3: Remove all media data, from this track buffer, that contain starting timestamps greater than or equal to start and less than the remove end timestamp.

So the user agent will remove all the data you've requested, from 0 to 8s

Then
Step 3.4: Remove all possible decoding dependencies on the coded frames removed in the previous step by removing all coded frames from this track buffer between those frames removed in the previous step and the next random access point after those removed frames.

The user agent will remove all frames that depend on the ones you've just removed. Due to the way h264 works (and all modern video codec) that is all frames following the last keyframe until the next keyframe, as none of those frames can now be decoded.

There is no keyframe in range 8 to 10s, so they are all removed

> Why do the later appendBuffer calls do nothing? I would expect them to
>   re-populate the SourceBuffer.

You have removed data, as per spec, the next frame you add must be a keyframe. If the segment you add contains no keyframe, nothing will be added.

If the data you add is made of a single keyframe at the start followed by just P-frame, then you can't remove any frames in the middle without rendering unusable all the ones that follow

Comment: Ah, this makes a lot of sense. Would a reasonable solution be to have more keyframes (I'm presuming in the data I'm currently simply has the one keyframe at the beginning created)?

Comment: MSE requires regular keyframes, otherwise you would never be able to delete any frames ever, including once your source buffer is full and you want to evict data. There is a ongoing discussion on how we could make such content usable by MSE: that would require disabling seeking in particular.

Comment: I've just tested the default behaviour (no manual buffer removal - just keep appending) in Firefox and it works fine. The buffer appears to get automatically rotated to avoid the QuotaExceededError?

This seems to have be an expected behavior of Chrome as well but has before been a problem with high bandwidth (we're doing about 6MB/s). This bug looks very familiar but was supposedly addressed in 2016. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=563292

Comment: If your content is made of a single keyframe at the start and none after, you *will* his QuotaExceededError. It's just a matter of time. The sourcebuffer maximum size is 100MiB in Firefox and 150MiB in Chrome